# How can I skip to the end of a UIViewPropertyAnimator animation?

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I have a variable with a `UIViewPropertyAnimator *` which is currently in the process of animating. For example, here's a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` named `fadeOutAnimator`, which "fades out" a UILabel (named `label`), and then removes it from its superview:

```
UIViewPropertyAnimator *fadeOutAnimator = [[UIViewPropertyAnimator alloc] initWithDuration:1.5f curve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
    [label setAlpha:0.0f];
}];

[fadeOutAnimator addCompletion:^(UIViewAnimatingPosition finalPosition) {
    [label removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Let's say that some other event happens in my app that makes me want to have this animation skip to the end, and execute its completion handler.

I've tried using the [stopAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimating/1649750-stopanimation?language=objc) method with both its `YES` and `NO` arguments, but in both cases, the animation display just appears to halt at its current progress; it doesn't advance to the end.

How can I make the animation immediately skip to the end, and execute its completion handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by setting the [fractionComplete](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimating/1649787-fractioncomplete?language=objc) property of the `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to `1.0` (i.e. 100% complete). Example:

```
[fadeOutAnimator setFractionComplete:1.0f];
```

This does immediately advance the animation to its ending state, and triggers a call to the completion handler(s) (if any).